# How to avoid CORS issues when connecting to MongoDB Realm GraphQL endpoint with Axios?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-realm, mongodb-cloud

I have a test database in MongoDB Atlas. Using the MongoDB Realm service, I've been able to set up a GraphQL endpoint for the database.

I can run queries internally with their sandbox (GraphiQL).

[image: graphiql]

After configuring the API key auth provider...

[image: api key]

[image: allow request origins]

...I was able to run queries externally from Postman, calling `https://realm.mongodb.com/api/client/v2.0/app/<MY_APP_ID>/graphql`.

[image: postman]

However, trying to make the same call using axios...

```
await axios({
  method: 'POST',
  url:
    'https://realm.mongodb.com/api/client/v2.0/app/<MY_APP_ID>/graphql',
  headers: {
    apiKey: '<MY_API_KEY>',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  data: {
    query: `
      {
        item {
          _id
          name
          description
        }
      }
    `
  }
})
```

...gives a CORS error.

[image: cors error]

Is there something I need to configure in Realm or a header that I'm missing to allow external access to the GraphQL endpoint from the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After discovering the [Task Tracker (web) tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/tutorial/web-graphql/) in the MongoDB Realm documentation I realized the issue. I needed to use the Realm javascript SDK to log in to Realm using my app ID and an auth provider.

You can use any auth providers you've enabled in the Realm dashboard (username/password, API key, Google, etc.) but they all return a single bearer token on sign in. This bearer token is what allows cross-domain querying of the GraphQL endpoint.

I also broke down and decided to install Apollo Client to do all the talking to the endpoint. The source for the React solution I ultimately ended up implementing can be [found here](https://github.com/mongodb-university/realm-tutorial). It uses a `RealmApp` to communicate with Realm and a `RealmApolloProvider` to talk to GraphQL with the proper Realm auth token.

Comment: I actually have the same exact issue, except I am tying to pass a custom JWT through as shown in the [Realm Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/graphql/authenticate/#custom-jwt). It is confusing because the docs seem like you can just pass in through the header but gives a CORS error like yours. I want to shy away from adding the realm-web package if possible because I am using another auth solution and don't want to have both. Did you happen to find any other leads for this other than using the realm-web package? I just want to use fetch to query the GraphQL endpoint

Comment: @mcdev You need to pass the custom JWT to the realm-web sign in to get the bearer token. Without that bearer token the GraphQL endpoint doesn't accept CORS connections. You pretty much need the realm-web package to do this unless you reverse engineer their sign in process. The upside of the realm-web library is that it can do all the token storage, refreshing, etc. on your behalf.

Comment: totally get it, thanks! I'm going to see if I can contact MongoDB and at the very least, I will just use the package. It seems odd to me why they would even highlight the ability to pass in a JWT as the header and allow Request Origins if the only way to access is to request a Bearer Token. The  the only reason I'm hesitant is I don't want to complicate things as I am already storing tokens etc for my auth process. But thanks for the reply. I will keep you updated if they respond

Comment: @mcdev it very well may be old documentation since I literally had the `api-key` header change to `apiKey` from one day to the next while i was working my way through this. As of writing this, Realm is a relatively new acquisition and they're still migrating a lot of their Stitch documentation to be aligned with Realm.